# How to restart an interval automatically after cleared it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, settimeout, slideshow

Im creating a slideshow which is running automatically when i load the page and it will stop if someone press the prev/next buttons (clearInterval). My problem is that i would like the interval restart after sometime and after it was cleared. I've tried with setTimeout but i think that im doing something wrong.

The slider it's based on an "ul" with images inside, and it will show each one of them by changing the margin of the list.
The buttons are placed on the sides of the list with a "data-mov" attribute that it will return "prev" or "next" saving that value in a variable called "dir".

I leave the actual js code that i have, the crucial point is within the "slide" function i believe.

Thank you so much in advance!

```
( function(){

var slider = $( '.slider' );

var slides = slider.find("li").length;

var actual = 0;

var width = 310;

var interval = setInterval( function(){
    slide( 'next' );
}, 1500 );


function slide( dir, click ){

    if ( click ){
       clearInterval( interval );
    }

    ( dir === "next" ) ? actual -- : actual ++;
    if ( actual > 0 ) {
        actual = ( slides - 1 ) *  -1;
    }else if ( actual <= ( slides * -1  ) ) {
        actual = 0;
    }
    var margin = actual * width;

    slider.animate({
        marginLeft: margin
    }, 450);

}

$('.btn-slide').on('click', function () {

    var dir = $(this).data("mov");
//when the button is pressed we send "true" for the "click" argument
    slide( dir , true);
});

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using setTimout is, in my opinion, a completely valid way to restart your slideshow.

You could easily achieve your target by doing this:

```
     var restartTimer;
     function slide( dir, click ){
        if ( click ){
           clearInterval( interval );
           clearTimeout(restartTimer);

           restartTimer = setTimeout(function () {
               setInterval(slide, 1500, 'next');
           }, 10000); // insert time after which you want it to continue here  
        }

        ( dir === "next" ) ? actual -- : actual ++;
        if ( actual > 0 ) {
            actual = ( slides - 1 ) *  -1;
        }else if ( actual <= ( slides * -1  ) ) {
            actual = 0;
        }
        var margin = actual * width;

        slider.animate({
            marginLeft: margin
        }, 450);
    }
```

The setTimout will restart it after (in this case) 10000ms, except if you happen to manually move the slider, then the timeout will be reset by the clearTimeout function. And it will wait from that point until the 10000ms have elapsed, after which it will continue again.

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked :D. The only thing now is when i press two times a button, then the animation goes two times as well, like if the action of pressing the button is not cleaning the interval or timeout before starts again

Comment: Oh that's logical because you didn't check whether the previous animation has ended yet, (the 450ms one) You could fix this by adding a variable 'lastButtonPress' and give it a timestamp using new Date(), and check whether the difference between lastButtonPress and new Date() is bigger than your animation length (450ms)

Comment: Im confused: both "clear" functions doesn't supposed to kill the execution?. If we press the button just once, the sider works fine but, if we press it two or more times the slider will run as many time i pressed the button and then it will wait what the interval was set. The logical im getting so far is: i press the button then the functions clearTimeout and clearInterval will be executed (killing the interval and animation), after that a new timeout it set starting the animation again. Why if i press two times the button, the setTimeout runs two times if im killing it before?.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, im a rookie about coding, and thank you!

Comment: That's because you're not killing the animation you're killing the timeout which will restart the animation, the actual slide animation is down at slider.animate.

Comment: Thanks Florisweb! I've tried to do what you said in order to check that but not luck, dont know how to. But this question it's solved. Thanks